# Нужна помощь в php нанесение вотрмарок

Tags: php

Есть код, который наносит на фото в формате .jpg другое фото в формате .png

Но проблема с размером png, ибо на маленьких jpg вотермарка большая, а на больших наоборот

**Нужно чтобы ширина вотермарки ровнялась 20% от ширины исходного изображения**
[image]
[image]

```
// получаем имя изображения
$image = "http://lurkmore.so/images/thumb/f/f0/KA50.jpg/350px-KA50.jpg"; 
// создаём водяной знак
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng('watermark.png');   

// получаем значения высоты и ширины водяного знака
$watermark_width = imagesx($watermark);
$watermark_height = imagesy($watermark);  

// создаём jpg из оригинального изображения
$image_path = $image;
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_path);
//если что-то пойдёт не так
if ($image === false) {
    return false;
}
$size = getimagesize($image_path);
// помещаем водяной знак на изображение
$dest_x = $size[0] - $watermark_width - 5;
$dest_y = $size[1] - $watermark_height - 5;

imagealphablending($image, true);
imagealphablending($watermark, true);
// создаём новое изображение
imagecopy($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height);
imagejpeg($image);

// освобождаем память
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($watermark);
```

Comment: После получения изображения, берете его ширину, расчитываете 20% и масштабируете watermark до этой ширины, после этого накладываете его на изображение.

Comment: как имеенно в кодом это сделать?